# How much transfer time do I need between ferry and train in Travemünde?

Tags: trains, public-transport, germany, short-connections, ferries

I want to take the ferry from Malmö to Travemünde. How much transfer time do I need to plan for if I want to take the train from station "Skandinavienkai"?

The ferry I want to take is scheduled to arrive at 7:15. Is it reasonable to buy a ticket for the train leaving at 7:39?

Comment: From the ferry you will be taken by Shuttlebus to the **Hafenhaus** which is about 50 m away from the train station. With any small delay, you would miss that train.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks, I didn't get that the bus was between ferry and Hafenhaus. But isn't the station more like 2km from the Hafenhaus, so my planned connection is completely impossible?

Comment: Indeed. The expansion of the harbour (for which they even moved the railway a bit to the West) means that you can no longer walk between the Terminal and that station. Except via a detour. There are plans to build a new station in a more convenient place though, but I guess that a bus every 15 minutes is quite acceptable for the people working in the Hafenhaus, and the few foot passengers. 
The bus apparently can take a direct route across the harbour, that pedestrians can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finnlines has instructions for foot passengers on its website:

https://www.finnlines.com/ferry-trips/contact/harbours-and-driving-instructions/travemunde

It contains the following mention:

> Please be aware that there is no walkway from the Lübeck-Travemünde
> Skandinavienkai train station to the Skandinavienkai Terminal.

As a foot passenger you will be taken off the ferry in a mini bus and driven to the terminal building. From there regular busses run to Lübeck and Travemünde.

So you can go to [www.bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de) and plan a trip...

From: "Skandinavienkai Terminal, Lübeck""

To: Pretty much anywhere in Europe....

So there is no need to get to the train Skandinavienkai train station.

Note that for regional travel there is no need to buy tickets in advance, and since (as is common in Germany) the tariff system is mode-neutral you cannot even buy a ticket for the 7:39 train, even if you wanted to...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't understand that the shuttle bus goes from the ferry to the terminal, I thought it goes around the harbour. That's good information! Do you have any experience how long it usually takes to get off the ferry and out of the terminal?

Comment: For security reasons it is nowadays no longer permitted for people to just wander around harbours. Which is why many ferries even don't take foot passengers anymore. The procedure is that you usually board the shuttle on the car deck, and then drive out. How long this takes depends. When I arrived in Zeebrugge  it was more than 1 1/2 hours even before I was even out of the harbour.

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question. I was wondering too at what time I would roughly be able to get on the bus from the terminal. Does it depend on the weather? Is the orricial arrival time when off-boarding is expected to start, or is it the time when I'll arrive at the terminal via shuttle bus? Does off-boarding take an hour or two? Can you share any more insights in that regard?

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at a map of the area, my instinct is that this would be very tight. Probably doable with a taxi but not likely on foot is my rough assessment of the matter.

However, a more important question is, does it matter? What sort of train journey are you making? If it is a relatively local one (within Schleswig-Holstein, or to Hamburg) it is quite likely that the ticket you are looking at is a low, local fare which does not tie you to any particular train, and so it would not matter from a ticket booking perspective if you missed the train you were aiming for. On the other hand if you're making a longer-distance journey this probably would matter.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen yes, my answer was assuming you walk the route that you can walk, ie out the main entrance of the harbour area and then up on the pavement (cycle route?) that parallels Ivendorfer Landstrasse... I can't see why you wouldn't be allowed to walk that way. As for the why, I didn't question it perhaps because I'm a train nerd myself and so would never consider taking a bus if there's an inconveniently sited railway station nearby ;)

Comment: Sorry, I only understood now after reading the other answer that the shuttle bus is going between ferry and terminal, not around the harbour! Then your answer of course makes perfect sense. I tried to delete my comment, but you were quicker with your answer... I will have another look.

Comment: If you really want to maximise time on the rails than take the bus not in the direction of Lübeck, but in the other direction, and this for one stop. That will get you to the Skandinavienkai train station. Or continue and hang out in Travemünde till the next train...